# Array to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist

I'm struggling with the "Test" class. I am getting an error (The method addStudent(ArrayList) in the type Course is not applicable for the arguments (String)) and I don't understand why.

Here is the main class:

```
public class Course {

    private String courseName;
    private ArrayList<String> students = new ArrayList<>();
    private int numberOfStudents;

    public Course(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public void addStudent(ArrayList students) {
        this.students = students;
        students.add(students);
        numberOfStudents ++;
    }

    public ArrayList getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public int getNumberOfStudents() {
        return numberOfStudents;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void dropStudents(ArrayList students) {
        this.students = students;
        students.remove(students);
        numberOfStudents --;
    }

}
```

Then this is what I have so far for the TestCourse class:

```
public class TestCourse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Course course1 = new Course("Data Structures");
        Course course2 = new Course("Database Systems");

        course1.addStudent("Peter Jones");
    }

}
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: `"Peter Jones"` is a `String`, not an `ArrayList`...I think you want to change your `public void addStudent(ArrayList students) {` method to take a `String` and add that `String` to a preexisting `ArrayList`...

Comment: and `students.add(students);` seems like a weird thing to do. You are adding an ArrayList to itself here. That method parameter should probably not be an `ArrayList`, but a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in here:

```
 public void addStudent(ArrayList students) {
        this.students = students;
        students.add(students);
        numberOfStudents ++;
 }
```

Change the argument from ArrayList to String.

```
 public void addStudent(String studentName) {
        students.add(studentName);
        numberOfStudents ++;
 }
```

Your `ArrayList<String> students` holds a collection of students. In your `addStudent` method, you will be adding one student per method invocation. Hence, `addStudent(String studentName)`.

Comment: How would I go about adding info to the ArrayList?

Comment: @Monocyte You add items to the arraylist simply by using the arraylist's method - arraylistName.add(item_to_be_added). It is as straight forward as that.

Answer (score 0):

Your method parameter is expecting `ArrayList` but you are passing a `String` as argument. Change the method parameter to `String` as shown below.

```
public void addStudent(String studentName) {
        students.add(studentName);
        numberOfStudents ++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass an array where you only need to pass a string..

```
public void addStudent(String studentName)
{
    students.add(studentName);
    numberOfStudents++;
}
```

If I was you I'd have another class for student because I have a feeling that you are going to have other information you'd have to store for student.